# Some arm64 system image missing when creating AVD

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

[image]

I need to use an arm64 Android 11 image with Google Play support.
Previously it was there, but it is gone, the latest S release doesn't work for me, I'll need versions higher than Android 8 but lower than Android S.

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this happens after updating from 4.1.2 to 4.2 stable on macOS Big Sur.
Downgraded to 4.1.2 fixed this.